# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'

Tags: python, django

Al subir una imagen al servidor, me devuelve el siguiente error:

ERROR: **'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'**

**Models.py**

```
def upload_to(instance, filename): #Esta función genera el directorio al modelo ImageInstallation.
    return 'img/installations/{}/{}'.format(instance.installation.id, filename)

class ImageInstallation(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Título',max_length=50,null=True, blank=True)
    installation = models.ForeignKey(Installation, related_name="installation_image",on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True, blank=True)
    image_imageInstallation = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_to)
    datetime = models.DateField ('FechaImagen',null=True, blank=True)
    mainPicture = models.BooleanField('Imagen principal', default=False, null=True, blank=True)
    pictureDescription = models.TextField('Descripción de la imagen', null=True,blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       instance = super(ImageInstallation, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
       image = Image.open(self.image_imageInstallation.path)
       image.save(self.image_imageInstallation.path,quality=20,optimize=True)
       return instance

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Imagen instalación'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Imagen de instalaciones'
        ordering = ['name']

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.image_imageInstallation)
```

Comment: el problema esta en la funcion uplaod to ya que el parametro que le estas pasando como instance no tiene el atributo id,es un error

Comment: Me paso ese mismo problema, y el error estaba entre la vista y el template. si quieres que te ayude sube la vista y el template